# AWS CodeDeploy - update-deployment-group related error

Tags: aws-code-deploy

I want to add a trigger to an existing DeploymentGroup. When I tried to execute the below update-deployment-group CLI command, it is giving me an error.

Error Message :

> Expecting ':' delimiter: line 1 column 160 (char 159)
>
> ```
> aws deploy update-deployment-group --application-name CodeDeployDemo --current-deployment-group-name CDPerf
> --trigger-configurations '[{"triggerName":"CodeDeployPerf","triggerTargetArn":"arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxx:tname","triggerEvents":{"DEPLOYMENT_START"}}]'
> ```

I've tried to follow what is in Page 183 of the [CodeDeploy user guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-user.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a documentation bug.

As described in the [API doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateDeploymentGroup.html),  `"triggerEvents":{"DEPLOYMENT_START"}` should be `"triggerEvents":["DEPLOYMENT_START"]`. So the whole command would be

```
$ aws deploy update-deployment-group --application-name CodeDeployDemo --current-deployment-group-name CDPerf --trigger-configurations '[{"triggerName":"CodeDeployPerf","triggerTargetArn":"arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxx:tname","triggerEvents":["DEPLOYMENT_START"]}]'
```

Comment: Also triggerEvents should be represented as, "triggerEvents":["DeploymentStart","DeploymentSuccess","DeploymentFailure","DeploymentStop"] . Otherwise, an error will come up - "A client error (InvalidTriggerConfigException) occurred when calling the UpdateDeploymentGroup operation: Invalid Trigger event type"

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the API doc @quiver suggests is the right version, and CodeDeploy user guide has a typo there. I've informed our doc write to help make it right. Basically everything inside {} is an object, and everything inside [] is a list of strings/objects etc.

Thanks for sharing your questions!